# Slideshow caption when logged in displays in different location when logged out

Tags: views, theming

I've got a slideshow displaying on the homepage, and at the bottom of the images, I've got captions. I am using:

```
.views-field-body { margin-top: 250px; }
```

To position the caption, but the position is not consistent when logged in and out. For example, the code above displays the caption in the correct location when logged out, but when logged in, the caption is pushed further down.

What is the correct way to position the caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this problem is not just for admin, its for all users with access to administer views.

Since the user have access to administer views, Drupal views adds some additional classes to provide contextual-links and wrappers for easy edit of that particular view.

I think, you must have used `position` attribute somewhere in your css for that particular field or the container holding that `div` you mentioned, which gets contradicted to the attributes provided by contextual wrapper classes.

See if you really need that attribute, or write one more css property for admin too.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your CSS by log in as an administrator. Try those of you who have Google chrome installed.

1. Go to **Option**
2. Open a new incognito window (or shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+N**)

and check your css there when you logged in as an administrator. The extra space your slogan is getting is due to the edit this link and all other links which are for administrator use only.For a normal user these links are not available (which is the case when you logged out) so it works fine.